# Configuring Authorization Policies in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel Docs ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization ) say that we have to modify `AuthServiceProvider` to configure policies. However this file resides in vendor folder ( `app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth`). We are not supposed to do any changes in vendor folder so how should I modify `AuthServiceProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`, and the docs mean this file.